# Как отключить видео и аудио в ioquake 3

Tags: c

Мне нужно запустить ioquake 3 на vps. Как вы понимаете на сервере не нужно видео и аудио игры. Плюс видео система клиента ioquake 3 иногда виснет.
В общем мне нужно чтобы клиент игры, да именно клиент, запускался на vps без видео и аудио.
Как это сделать?
Я знаю про s_audioinit.

Comment: Объясните зачем это понадобилось...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:
seta s_volume "0" и seta s_musicvolume "0"

Comment: А как видео отключить чтобы вообще его не было?

Comment: К сожалению так не получится. Вот список всех команд: https://sinl.narod.ru/Quake.htm

Comment: Даже если код поменять? Там, закоментировать в коде что нибудь?